# Model names from ViewModel in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public BandProfileModel BandProfile { get; set; }
    public MusicanProfileModel MusicianProfile { get; set; }
    public RegularProfileModel RegularProfile { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using this ViewModel In my View to Post a form:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterBand", "NewProfile", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
        }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        Bandname
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.BandProfile.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.BandProfile.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here Is my RegisterBand model:

```
  public ActionResult RegisterBand(BandProfileModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }


            return View("Index");
        }
```

The problem I have is that the name-attribute of Input fields are BandProfile.Name, BandProfile.Genre, instead of just Genre and Name.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, you can also use `public ActionResult RegisterBand([Bind(Ptefix = "BandProfile")] BandProfileModel model)` which effectively strips the prefix when binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just change your `RegisterBand` ActionResult to accept a `ProfileViewModel`.

```
public ActionResult RegisterBand(ProfileViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
    {
        return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

Your `HttpPost` needs to accept an instance of the same object that you pass into the form, otherwise it won't know what names to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the name and id of control you can do it like this

```
 @Html.EditorFor(x => x.BandProfile.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id="Genre",@Name="Genre"  } })
```